# Information About the Available Options Of The \setmathfont Command

Tags: unicode-math

I am using the `unicode-math` package and I am loading the STIX2 math font as following

```
\setmathfont[
  Path = Fonts/STIX2Math/,
  Scale = 1.1
]{STIX2Math.otf}
```

My problem is that I can't find in the documentation of the `unicode-math` package anything regarding the available options I can use with the `\setmathfont` command like the `Path` and `Scale`.

I found the options I already use online but I can't find any other information about options in general to the point that if the command wasn't working for me right now, I would be almost certain those options were not available. Where can I find further information?

Comment: Those are documented in the Fontspec manual. Generally, the capitalized options like `Scale=` are Fontspec options, and lowercase options are Unicode-Math options.

Comment: In this case, you almost certainly do **not** want `Path=`, as `STIX2Math.otf` is already available in every TeX distribution and should be found automatically. The exception would be if you wanted to archive a specific version. A `Scale=` option should almost always be `Scale=MatchLowercase` (if you’re mostly using letters like *x* and *y*) or `Scale=MatchUppercase` (if you’re mostly using tall math symbols like ℝ and ).

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for your reply! What `unicode-math` has to do with `fontspec`? Because I load all my fonts manually, I do know about the options of `fontspec` as they are well documented, but I don't see how these two packages are connected. I know that STIX2 are in the distribution but I was already loading it like that, and I generally prefer doing it manually. I face no problem with fonts but I was just wondering about the options.

Comment: Unicode-Math is built on top of Fontspec and inherits all its options. I can see how someone not aware of that would get confused!

Comment: @Davislor That explains everything! Feel free to write that as an answer so to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you peruse it very carefully, [section 4 of the `unicode-math` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf#6) tells you, “Other `fontspec` features are also valid.”  Easy to miss, but that’s where it’s documented.  The `unicode-math` package is built on top of `fontspec` and inherits all of its options.

In general, uppercase options such as `Scale=` are [`fontspec` options,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)  and lowercase options such as `range=` and `version=` are `unicode-math` options.