# Setting separate non-open TTF/OTF fonts for regular and italic in maths and xelatex

Tags: xetex, overleaf, mathspec

I'm writing an Overleaf document in which I would like to use Adobe Garamond Pro as my maths typeface. The problem is I have separate files for the Regular TTF and the Italic TTF (also available as OTF-files).

This means I have to do it with xelatex (because you can't import non-standard fonts into Overleaf with PDFlatex). I also have to do it with mathspec rather than unicode-math since I don't have a math-friendly font-file. But I don't seem to be able to do it with mathspec since I have separate fiels for regular and italic.

If I try for instance the code below, I will not get the Garamond font for maths. There are many variants of this (like how to write the setmathfont-key), but none of them work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

%% For Matspec
\usepackage{mathspec}
       \makeatletter
       \let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage % Get around amsmath before mathspec-warning
       \makeatother

%% For Unicode-math
% \usepackage{unicode-math} % uncomment if mathspec is used

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{AGaramondPro}[
    Path=./fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic]

%% For Unicode-math
% \setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
% \setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.ttf}[range=up/{Latin,num}]
% \setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}[range=it/{Latin,latin}]

%% For Mathspec
\setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){./fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}
 
\begin{document}
$h$ \textit{h}
\end{document}
```

And if I try the code below here, with unicode-math, I just get a warning saying the font is not found.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

%% For Matspec
% \usepackage{mathspec}
%        \makeatletter
%        \let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage % Get around amsmath before mathspec-warning
%        \makeatother

%% For Unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math} % uncomment if mathspec is used

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{AGaramondPro}[
    Path=./fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic]

%% For Unicode-math
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
\setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.ttf}[range=up/{Latin,num}]
\setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}[range=it/{Latin,latin}]

%% For Mathspec
% \setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){./fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}
 
\begin{document}
$h$ \textit{h}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to work around this?

[Edit: I updated the OP with full "working" examples (given you have the corrent font in the correct folder). The reason for using h in the print is because it is easy to identify the differences in the typeface in that letter. "Garamond-math" renders a similar, but not identical result. Before I print the thesis, I would like them to be identical...]

Comment: well I would use unicode math, start with a real math font (as you need a math table) and then exchange with range some of the symbols. I would avoid mathspec or mathfont (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487319/2388 for the reason).

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, but using ...
´´´
  \setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
  \setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.ttf}[range=up/{Greek,Latin,num}]
  \setmathfont{./fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}[range=it]
```
... will just result in the PDF not compiling, the first error is "missing number, treated as zero".

Comment: don't do \setmathfont{./fonts/AGara  just use the font name and specify any path in the Path= key

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, but I don't think there is a path-key in Unicode-math? The code in my response to Ulrike Fischer seems to find the font-file, because I get a "The font cannot be found"-error if I misspell/change the filename.

Comment: the options are passed on to fontspec, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584831/information-about-the-available-options-of-the-setmathfont-command

Comment: you have not provided any example anyone can run, and `\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage % Get around amsmath before mathspec-warning` looks highly likely to break stuff but with no runnable example, hard to tell.

Comment: I updated the OP with full examples, but they will not work unless you have the correct fonts in the correct folder. (Well, they will not work anyway...) For now I will use "\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}" because it is close enough.

Comment: Wait, the path thing did it! I'll add an answer for clarity later. Thanks, @DavidCarlisle!

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidCarlisle pointed out, the path should be given in another way than in my initial unicode-math example: [Information About the Available Options Of The \setmathfont Command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584831/information-about-the-available-options-of-the-setmathfont-command)

I looked through the unicode-math documentation after how to give the path but missed that it inherits keys from fontspec.

So, as @UlrikeFischer also showed, the best way in this case is to first set a default, fully functional math font, and then build onto that with ranges, as shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{AGaramondPro}[
    Path=./fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic]

\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
\setmathfont[Path=fonts/]{AGaramondPro-Regular.ttf}[range=up/{Latin,num}]
\setmathfont[Path=fonts/]{AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf}[range=it/{Latin,latin}]
 
\begin{document}
$h$ \textit{h}
\end{document}
```

This way the h-s at the bottom turn out exactly identical.